# Laravel Pivot table not plural

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

Why do Laravel ask for a pivot table as singular, in my code? How do I fix so it call as plural?

**Database tables**

- users (id, etc)
- campaigns (id, etc)
- campaign_users (user_id, campaign_id)

**Code**

My campaign model, and campaign_user model are pretty much empty, and generated by artisan. But here are my user relation to campaigns, in User model:

```
public function playing_campaigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Sagohamnen\campaign\campaign');
    }
```

Here I call DB to get the campaigns, in which the user are part of:

```
$user = user::with(['playing_campaigns'])->where('id', $id)->get();
```

**SQL error**

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'sagohamnen.campaign_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `campaigns`.*,
>   `campaign_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
>   `campaign_user`.`campaign_id` as `pivot_campaign_id` from `campaigns`
>   inner join `campaign_user` on `campaigns`.`id` =
>   `campaign_user`.`campaign_id` where `campaign_user`.`user_id` in (1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongsToMany` takes a second parameter for the table name...

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Sagohamnen\campaign\campaign', 'campaign_users');
```

This is just the standards that Laravel assumes to try and make our lives easier.

Comment: also checkout the documentation here for other parameters you can pass [Many-to-many documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for answering. If understand the documentation right, one should not need to add second argument, if the tables are named according Laravel convention. "Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order". Hm, though I added the second argument to see if any changed happen. The result was a blank array, hm.

Comment: It's alphabetical order and singular so your table should be `campaign_user`.  If it's an empty array being returned, ensure you have the data inserted for that user id you are using.  It also helps to turn on the general log on your DB and watch the queries which are being run and make sure they make sense.

Comment: Oh, so the pivot table must be named in singular. That part I did not notice!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that's not in the documentation, I'm pretty sure at one point it was.

Comment: One problem is though if I use campaign_user::find(1)->first(), since it expects an plural name of the table. I guess one solution is to add: protected $table = 'campaign_user' in campaign_user model.

Comment: `find(1)` would return a single model so you shouldn't use `first()` after that because it will result in an error.  If you were getting a collection back, then you'd use `first()` then to grab the first item in the collection.  Also, it's usually not required to create a `Campaign_User` model.  You should be able to manage that table through the `Campaign` and `User` models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122382/discussion-between-olof84-and-user3158900).